# Postfix/Gmail smtp relay invalid credentials for relay

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, centos7, g-suite

I have a centos7 vm running a postfix using gsuite SMTP relay without authentication on port 587. I am able to successfully send email from the server itself. When I try to send email using a client, I am getting the following error:

" host smtp-relay.gmail.com[173.194.208.28] said: 550-5.7.1
Invalid credentials for relay [my public IP]. The IP address you've
550-5.7.1 registered in your G Suite SMTP Relay service doesn't match
domain of 550-5.7.1 the account this email is being sent from. If you are
trying to relay 550-5.7.1 mail from a domain that isn't registered under
your G Suite account 550-5.7.1 or has empty envelope-from, you must
configure your mail server 550-5.7.1 either to use SMTP AUTH to identify
the sending domain or to present 550-5.7.1 one of your domain names in the
HELO or EHLO command. For more 550-5.7.1 information, please visit 550"

After adding the following lines in my /etc/postfix/main.cf file,

```
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
smtp_helo_name = <mydomain.com>
```

I started getting the "Undelivered mail return to sender" email with the error mentioned above.

I have checked my gsuite admin settings and my IP address is registered. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to follow the directions that it gave you.

Comment: I did that. I added my domain to the HELO command. no luck.

Comment: You also need to check that the domain is in G Suite. And that you used the correct IP address.